How does English grammar define dependent and independent clauses?
I'm confused
Here's what I used to believe (still do, actually). In English, you put a comma between independent clauses (like in Russian). You don't put a comma between an independent and dependent clause, in that order (unlike in Russian)
But then I got spelling checkers and GPT telling me I got it all wrong, and that, in fact, I should put a comma in sentences like this one

It was raining, so I took an umbrella

I believe the confusion comes from how independent and dependent clauses are defined in English
In Russian, "so I took an umbrella" would, I believe, be considered a dependent clause because it doesn't make sense on its own (because of that "so")
I figure it may be different in English grammar after all
I noticed this weird thing. In English, they apply this test too: they take a simple sentence out and see if it can work on its own. If it can, its an independent clause. If it can't, it's an dependent clause. However, during that test, they sometimes remove the conjunction. Other times, they don't. In the first case, they conclude the clause is independent; in the second case, they conclude it's dependent. But that doesn't have anything to do with clauses, it has everything to do with whether you remove the conjunction or not! Examples:

I'll land a new job if the interview goes well
Reasoning:
"If the interview goes well" doesn't make sense on its own, it's a dependent clause


It was raining, so I took an umbrella
Reasoning:
"I took an umbrella" does make sense on its own, that's why "so I took an umbrella" is an independent clause

Notice it has practical consequences: a comma is now necessary in the second example
So how does English define dependent and independent clauses, e.g. in the context of punctuation?
I did notice there are multiple similar questions (1, 2, 3), but I didn't find any of them helpful

In traditional grammar, so is among the coordinating conjunctions — it’s the s in FANBOYS. Coordinating conjunctions coordinate independent clauses. Use a comma with those.

@TinfoilHat but why are those considered coordinating, not subordinating conjunctions?

Because they coordinate clauses.

@TinfoilHat why is it considered coordination, not subordination, e.g. in the umbrella sentence?

Two independent clauses: It was raining. I took an umbrella. Two independent clauses coordinated: It was raining, so I took an umbrella. So, being a coordinating conjunction, has coordinated these clauses.

@TinfoilHat FANBOYS is at best a misguided learning aid for beginners. This article might help clear up some confusion.

@DW256 — As I mentioned, FANBOYS is a traditional reading. All the same, being “acculturated into the myth” helps people wrap their heads around prescriptive concepts that are otherwise opaque.

@TinfoilHat The point is that FANBOYS does the exact opposite of 'help people wrap their heads around prescriptive concepts', as evidenced by the OP's confusion after having been exposed to 'traditional' 'prescriptive' concepts: the obvious logical inconsistencies become apparent to the student after even the most basic reflection.

@TinfoilHat we're going in circles. Why is it independent? -> Because "so" is a coordinating conjunction -> Why is it a coordinating conjunction? -> Because it coordinates clauses -> Why is it coordination? -> Because the clauses are independent

The same question has been posted on ELL. Cross posting is normally discouraged unless there's a good reason, such as a question being off-topic and closed on a previous site, or not attracting any answers for at least three days. This doesn't look like the case here.

@Mari-LouA actually, I was earlier told that cross-posting on SE is fine (I'm not sure I could find a link to that, though)

If the two posts are different questions tailored to the individual site, I think that's acceptable. The two questions you posted on EL&U and ELL are identical though. Why did you feel the need to repost the question? Did the accepted answer on ELL not satisfy you? Then you should explain it here. You could wait and see what happens.

@Mari-LouA ELL is for learners, ELU is for more seasoned English nerds. I was hoping to find an authoritative grammar reference that clearly defines the two terms. ELU, as I eventually concluded, was more suitable for that

"I was hoping to find an authoritative grammar reference that clearly defines the two terms" where does it say that IN the actual question? This is what I meant by tailoring a question for a specific site.

@Mari-LouA btw, I did tailor it somewhat, e.g. added the word "grammar" in the title


It was raining, so I took an umbrella.

Here, so I took an umbrella is an independent clause because you can use it as a standalone sentence:

It was raining. So I took an umbrella.

Simple as that. There's no reason to be confused.
There are many factors that determine comma usage other than syntax, so comma usage is unrelated to the dependent/independent dichotomy.

(1a) I'll land a new job if the interview goes well. 
(1b) I'll land a new job, if the interview goes well. 
(2a) If the interview goes well I'll land a new job.

(2b) If the interview goes well, I'll land a new job.

All four constructions above are possible, so comma usage has nothing to do with the dependent/independent dichotomy. Now, calling a clause either dependent or independent is not a terribly logical practice. In (1b), for example, if the interview goes well is neither a dependent nor an independent clause.
Now, recent grammars (such as The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language) analyze the interview goes well (without if) as a subordinate clause, and if as a preposition taking a subordinate clause as its complement.

"Here, so I took an umbrella is an independent clause because you can use it as a standalone sentence" It's interesting, 'cause I heard the opposite, that you can't start a sentence with a coordinating conjunction (and that's how you identify it)

@SergeyZolotarev And where did you hear such a silly thing? :)

@tchrist Here

@SergeyZolotarev "We cannot start a sentence with a coordinating conjunction. But this rule is broken many times and we can find sentences beginning with And, But." When a rule is broken many times, it's no longer a rule.

@ishtar Yes, technically, Because it was raining. can be a standalone sentence, just as can Because of rain. and If you'll excuse me. These can be a standalone sentence, not because they're independent clauses but because they contain a subordinate clause with the matrix frame omitted. So, yes, just because a clause (along with whatever comes before it) can be a standalone sentence doesn't mean it's an independent clause. But the standalone sentence So I took an umbrella. does go to show that it is an independent clause.
